# Is there a way in Webforms to tell, on pageload, if the postback was caused by an Ajax request or just a regular full postback?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I need to be able to determine that on the PageLoad event in codebehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to do that via [IsAsyncPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var isAjaxPostBack = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`IsInAsyncPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback(v=vs.110).aspx) of the ScriptManager class can be used. It will be true for a PartialUpdate/"AJAX" PostBack and false otherwise.

> [IsInAsyncPostBack] Gets a value that indicates whether the current postback is being executed in partial-rendering mode ..
>
> Use the IsInAsyncPostBack property in combination with the IsPostBack property to distinguish between the initial page load, a partial-page update, and a full-page update in *Load*, InitComplete, or PreRender events.